# Writing a DLNA server (DMS) in Cocoa/Objective-C/C

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, macos, dlna

I'd like to write a DLNA server in Cocoa for the Mac.  Are there any libraries for speaking UPnP/DLNA in Objective-C or C?  Failing that, where is the spec for DLNA so I can write my own?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this one:

http://code.google.com/p/upnpx/

Comment: hi I am getting linking issues in Xcode 6. Could you please help me

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Platinum UPnP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/platinum/). It's written in C++, but is very portable.

Comment: Awesome, it's got sample code for doing UPnP AV.  It *looks* like that's the same as DLNA.  If I'm getting this right, DLNA is a certification for UPnP protocols.

Comment: hey I am able to integrate it but when I click on the start it showing in the list of DLNA but it is not returning any folders.i.e music,albums...... Could you please help me

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the Platinum UPnP Framework too and I found it quite cumbersome to work with since the API is C++ and (fortunately or unfortunately I am not sure) I am not a very experienced C++ developer.

I found this which seems to look promising and has a nicer Objective-C API: [CyberLinkForObjC](http://www.cybergarage.org/twiki/bin/view/Main/CyberLinkForObjC)

Comment: Platinum has an Objective-C layer so you don't have to deal with C++ if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about DLNA, but if you want to do port mapping with UPnP, you can try [TCMPortMapper](http://code.google.com/p/tcmportmapper/).