# DLNA - DMC for iOS

Tags: ios

I'm trying to develop a DLNA controller (DMC) application for iOS which finds the content on the Digital Media Server ( DMS ) and sends the data to a Digital Media Renderer (DMR). So, is  there any open source library or framework for iOS which can be used for developing iOS DMC application?

As per my understanding, to develop a DMC application,  these are the steps to be followed to implement the application.

1. Discover the Digital Media Servers & Digital Media Renderers.
2. Browse the content of a DMS.
3. Send content to a DMR.

Please correct me if there is anything wrong in my understanding. Also please provide me if there is any library or framework available for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still interested in that topic, but found a library in an answer in another question: [Writing a DLNA server (DMS) in Cocoa/Objective-C/C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794561/writing-a-dlna-server-dms-in-cocoa-objective-c-c)

The answer mentions the library upnpx which got discontinued, but there exists a fork on github: https://github.com/fkuehne/upnpx

The demo application covers all the features/use cases you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score -2):

ZappoTV has an iOS SDK that you can use.

http://www.zappo.tv/sdk.html

You can add the DLNA UPnP AV functionality in a couple of hours and they have a easy revenue share business model that allows you to earn revenues from providing the Play2TV functionality to your app.

Comment: If you are directly involved with that site (and you seem to be, looking at your profile, please add some kind of disclaimer to your answer or it might get flagged as *spam*. See the [FAQ#promotion].